Infite loop in rabbit mq
I have this code and I am getting both the logs printed inifintely
@Autowired
    private C c;

    @RabbitListener(queues = "CQ")
    public void consumeAndPublish(Request request) {
        log.info("consuming and publishing "+ request.getUserId());
        c.publishCartCompensetingEvent(request);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "CC_QUEUE")
    public void consumeMessageTest(Request request) {
        log.info("CCQUEUE "+ request.getUserId());
    }

 @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    public void publish(Request request) {
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(E_EXCHANGE, CC_ROUTING_KEY, request);
    }

How can we fix the infite loop error
